# Error Querying database when insert PHP code is executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been tinkering with my PHP code to insert data into a SQL table and I always get ERROR QUERYING DATABASE. The values are coming from a normal HTML form and and then when I hit submit (action=memberadd.php) I get the error message from the code below. I'm missing something but can't see what it is????

```
    <?php 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];//only showing one - need to fix
    $profile_visibility = $_POST['profile_visibility'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $profile_link = $_POST['profile_link'];
    $skills = $_POST['skills'];


    //connects and sends information to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'main') or die('Error connecting to       MySQL server.');

   //inserts data into the member_details table main db
   $query = "INSERT INTO 'member_details' (first_name, last_name, city, state, country, industry, profile_visibility, position, status, profile_link, skills) 
   VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$industry', '$profile_visibility', '$position', '$status', '$profile_link', '$skills')";

   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Error querying database.');
   mysqli_close($dbc);

   echo '<h2>Here are your details.</h2>';
   echo '<h3>First Name: '.$first_name.'<br />';
   echo '<h3>Last Name: '.$last_name.'<br />';
   echo 'City: '.$city.'<br />';
   echo 'State: '.$state.'<br />';
   echo 'Country: '.$country.'<br />';
   echo 'Industry: '.$industry.'<br />';//only showing one - need to fix
   echo 'Profile: '.$profile_visibility.'<br />';
   echo 'Position: '.$position.'<br />';
   echo 'Status: '.$status.'<br />';
   echo 'Link: '.$profile_link.'<br />';
   echo 'Skills: '.$skills.'<br /></h3>';

   ?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes `INSERT INTO 'member_details'`

Comment: 56 answers stand to follow... (*for just 2 measly quotes*)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development. That will signal the error.

Comment: Change your `die()` call to show the error message: `or die('Error querying database. ' . mysqli_error($dbc))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- MySQL errors are not reported as PHP errors, you have to call `mysqli_error()` to get them.

Comment: @Barmar You have a point there and I will make a note of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

As [@Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) has [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818867/error-querying-database-when-insert-php-code-is-executed#comment36644225_23818867) the problem is with the quotes being around the table name in your `INSERT` statement.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'member_details' (first_name, ...
                      ^              ^
```

**The solution**

If you wish to 'quote' table or column names, you should use backticks which you can read more about on the [MySQL documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html).

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `member_details` (first_name, ...
```

**Detecting errors**

To check a MySQLi database request for errors there are a few methods that can be used to get error information. Probably the most useful is `mysqli_error()` which [will give you an error string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if(!$result)
{
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

As [@Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) also [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818867/error-querying-database-when-insert-php-code-is-executed#comment36644313_23818867) you should use error reporting correctly when developing new code. Ideally you should configure this in your php.ini, but it can also easily be done by adding the following to the top of your page(s).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Finally, you're wide open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. You should look into using [prepared statements with MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to help prevent this.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment above, enabling PHP error reporting would not cause this error to be reported. `mysqli` does not report database errors automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Ah yes, correct. So used to using PDO which will throw exceptions when properly set up. Edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql query like...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `member_details` SET first_name = '".$first_name."', last_name = '".$last_name."', city = '".$city."', state = '".$state."', country = '".$country."', industry = '".$industry."', profile_visibility = '".$profile_visibility."', position = '".$position."', status = '".$status."', profile_link = '".$profile_link."', skills = '".$skills."'";
```